# HTML PHP How to spit things out

Tags: php, html

i have a php file

```
    <?php
// Connect to database
mysql_connect("******************", "******", "******");
mysql_select_db("*******");

// If something is received
if($_POST)
{

        // Filter it to prevent SQL injections
        $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['stringdata']);

        // Search it on the database
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT `reply` FROM `poka` WHERE `word` = '$text' ORDER BY RAND()");

        // Show result
        if($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            echo $r['reply'];
        else
            echo "Cannot find a reply";
    }
    ?>
```

Basically, I can enter the word "HEY" into a text box and then it will reply with the reply from the word hey etc..

In my database i have 3 rows called ID, Word, Reply. Meaning if you enter the word "hey" into the text box it will go threw the database and then spit out a random reply from the words hey into a chat box thing like you are talking to a computer

Comment: In my database i have 3 rows called ID, Word, Reply. Meaning if you enter the word "hey" into the text box it will go threw the database and then spit out a random reply from the words hey into a chat box thing like you are talking to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the various HTML tags to make the output as HTML and/or put the HTML outside the PHP code i.e

```
?>
<p>This code is not parsed by PHP</p>
<?php
// More PHP code
```

Comment: Don't use shorthand PHP syntax. `<?php` not `<?`

Comment: Truth - That was a typo. Fixed it.